# Show some contents inside p:lightBox

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How to show some content inside light-box of primefaces as I have to show some information about the image as no. of likes,no. of comments,and also have to provide option to post comments so on and so forth?

On xhtml page I have written this:

```
<p:lightBox styleClass="imagebox"> 
    <c:forEach var="event1" items="#{event.files}" varStatus="cnt">

       <h:outputLink value="#{listOfFilesForEventBean.getImage854By480ProfileUrl(event1)}" title="#{event1.location.locationName}">  
           <h:graphicImage value="#{listOfFilesForEventBean.getImageIconProfileUrl(event1)}"/>  
       </h:outputLink> 


     </c:forEach>
</p:lightBox>
```

Where files is list of image profiles that I am iterating.
And I want along with the image which is displayed on lightbox some information about the image should be displayed.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried and what exactly is failing? The showcase example seems pretty clear.

Comment: if you can share any example then that would be a great help for me because I am naive with the primefaces.

Comment: You could find example here : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/lightBox.jsf and full documentation here: http://www.primefaces.org/documentation

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. If somebody is still looking for the answer here is my solution.
I did not find easy way to have some additional controls inside p:lightBox item.
Guess it assigns own JavaScript handlers to all its children and that makes a problem.
Also I had the problems with using commandButton inside ui:repeat. So I'm using my own implementation of p:lightBox and p:remoteCommand to call other actions(like post comments, delete image etc). Something like that:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="deleteImage" update="imagesGrid"
    actionListener="#{imageBean.deleteImage}" />


<h:panelGroup id="imagesGrid">
    <ui:repeat var="item" value="#{imageBean.list}">


        <div class="docThumbContainer">
            <div class="docPlaceholder"></div>
            <div class="docThumbImage">
                <h:outputLink value="/images?id=#{item.imageId}">
                    <h:graphicImage value="data:image/jpg;base64,#{item.thumbnail}"
                        alt="" />
                </h:outputLink>
            </div>
            <div class="docThumbButtons">
                <p:commandButton type="button" value="Delete"
                    onclick="deleteImage([{name:'imageId', value:#{item.imageId}}]);" />
            </div>
        </div>


    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>
```

ImageBean:

```
public void deleteImage(ActionEvent event) {
    ImageManager manager = getManager();
    manager.deleteImage(StringUtil.parseInt(getUrlParameter("imageId"), -1));
}
```

Of course it is simplified replacement for p:lightBox. To show the full image in the overlay with prev/next buttons you need additional work. E.g. using p:dialog etc